# NW.js how to show the file path and toolbar on window?

Tags: node.js, nw.js

I using the nw.js in windows 7 system, related teaching documents have the photo:

[image]

the top have a bar , can be show the project file path and reload buttons.
I don't know how to call this panel.

the `package.json` have a parameter `toolbar`:

```
"window": {
        "toolbar": true,
}
```

I don't know it's referring to this top bar?
but it's not work in my option.

[image]

If that operation can't reload,every edit source code must be re build nw window (`nw [project fold path]`), very inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nw.js v13.xx.x?
If so there's no toolbar (yet) in this version as per this [link](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3500#issuecomment-104164957).

But you could 'reload' from the context menu. That is right-click somewhere in the document.